# Ticktext of ColorBar output ontop of each other

Tags: python, plotly

I'm currently creating a plot in python using plotly. For some reason my colorbar ticktext keeps getting written on top of each other: [image]

Here is my code:

```
    for i in range(numOfPlots):
        data = DQLists[i]
        yaxis1 = ylists[i]
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data[:,1], y=yaxis1, mode='markers',
                                marker=dict(size=10, color=data[:,0], colorscale='viridis',
                                            colorbar=dict(title='Data Quality Level', 
                                                        ticktext=['Good Data Quality', 'Bad Checksum', 'Multiple Data Quality Issues'],
                                                        tickvals=[2, 3, 4],
                                                        xpad=10, ypad=10),),
                                name=titles[i],
                                showlegend=True))
        
    fig.update_layout(legend=dict(orientation='h',yanchor='top',y=1.1,
        xanchor='center',
        x=0.5,
        traceorder='normal',
    ),)  

    fig.update_layout(title="Test", xaxis_title="X Axis", yaxis_title="Y Axis")
    fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)

    fig.show()
```

I tried modifying the ticktexts in different ways but it has not helped me

Comment: for every iteration of the loop, you're using different `yaxis1` data, but the colorbar is [probably] going to change so hardcoding the location of the `tickvals=[2,3,4]` is going to lead to the ticktext overlapping itself. do you need more than one colorbar? what if you only plot the colorbar for one of the traces instead of every time you add a trace?